# How do I get the string location in Java

Tags: java, android

May be I'm asking something weird but I would like to know, where my string is  saved in java. I used `hashCode()`

```
String ext = getIntent().getStringExtra("title_");

        int path = ext.hashCode();
        Log.e("path", ""+path);
```

and I got the hashcode. so it this the only address of my string or there is other ways too, to get the location of string.

**UPDATE**

Actually I'm transferring the string between two activities. And every time I'm getting the same string. **Even if I changed the value then also I got the same string which** **I have transferred First time**.

> Activity one

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(GCMIntentService.this, MainActivity.class);

notificationIntent.putExtra ("title_",message);
```

> Activity Two

```
String ext = getIntent().getStringExtra("title_");

Log.e("path", ext);
```

Comment: The hash code is not a location. It's just a tool to let you use hash tables. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: umm just curious, why would you want the exact location of where a variable is stored? are you trying to figure out where the getIntent().getStringExtra("title_"); is stored?

Comment: what do you mean by activities? can you please share the code for the activities/processes that are communicating?

Comment: @CrazyCoder _get the location_ of string. You are asking where it stored in memory or String pool ?

Comment: @CrazyCoder have you tried a log statement in activity1 right before you add it to the intent? Just to make sure it is in fact changing.

Comment: @Thanigaiarasu could you please tell me about both

Comment: Welcome to Java and say hello to references and immutable objects. Answer per se is not bad (well formatted and to the points), so I don't think it should be downvoted.

Comment: @Dmitry No, it's not a good question. It doesn't ask what the problem is (why he is getting the same string), it doesn't show any class/method examples, and the hash code is a completely unrelated side track.

Comment: yes @Tomas that's the point I'm getting the same string that's why I want to know where it is stored so that I find out from where it is coming again and again even if I've changed the value.

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435361/push-notification-plugin-phonegape Please see this.

Answer (score 0):

First use this:

```
Intent i=new Intent(context,SendMessage.class);
i.putExtra("test", "This is a test");
context.startActivity(i);
```

Then in the other activity, get the intent which has started your activity using the getIntent() method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

If your extra data is represented as strings, then you can use intent.getStringExtra(String name) method. In this test:

```
String test = intent.getStringExtra("test");
```

In your case try:

One:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,SendMessage.class);

notificationIntent.putExtra ("title_",message);

context.startActivity(notificationIntent);
```

Two:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

String ext = intent.getStringExtra("title_");

Log.e("path", ext);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435361/push-notification-plugin-phonegape
Please see this

Answer (score 0):

First, an object's `hashCode` has *absolutely* nothing to do with its address.

Second, addresses aren't really something you should deal with in Java.

Java *does* have pointers, though. All non-primitive fields are "pointers" (*reference types*), and you *can* compare them to each other:

```
string1 == string2
```

This will actually compare the "addresses" of the two strings.

As the JLS puts it, [in 15.21.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3):

> At run time, the result of == is true if the operand values are both null or both refer to the same object or array; otherwise, the result is false.

Also:

> While == may be used to compare references of type String, such an equality test determines whether or not the two operands refer to the same String object. The result is false if the operands are distinct String objects, even if they contain the same sequence of characters ([§3.10.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435361/push-notification-plugin-phonegape Please see this